# while loop with try/catch error in Julia logic problem

Tags: while-loop, scope, julia, try-catch

I'm trying to write a while loop that tests whether an input is valid or not and it keeps asking if the user insists on the wrong input. If it is a valid one, the program just goes on. This is where i'm at.

```
while true
    try
        selected_row = readline()
        selected_row = parse(Int8, selected_row)
        break
    catch e
        if isa(e, LoadError)
            @warn "type a valid number between [1,8]"
        elseif isa(e, ArgumentError)
            @warn "type a valid number between [1,8]"
        end
    end
end

println("you chose (C|R) ($selected_row)")
```

The problem is that when the input is correct I get an error.

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: selected_row not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop creates a new scope. Now the way to fix the issue depends on where you put your code.

If it is inside e.g. a function then use:

```
local selected_row
```

before the loop (inside the function body) and things will work.

If your code is in top-level scope write:

```
global selected_row = parse(Int8, readline())
```

in your code which will guarantee that a global variable `selected_row` will be created.

Having said that I would recommend to write your code as follows:

```
function get_int8()
    while true
        selected_row = tryparse(Int8, readline())
        isnothing(selected_row) || return selected_row
    end
end

selected_row = get_int8()
```

Comment: wow, this isnothing() function is exactly what I was looking for. That's wonderful. Thank you!

Comment: @hcp just FYI, although Julia has try-catch, Julia leans toward if-statement-heavy LBYL (look before you leap) rather than try-catch-heavy EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission). Some people say that try-catch should be avoided because it's less performant, but I would say it's more of a clarity issue. LBYL is appropriate when you're checking for very specific things regularly, EAFP is appropriate when you're trying to handle freak accidents.